# Passing an argument to OnClick function by Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm automating a page using selenium. There is a text on a page "Show More Matches" with OnClick function at the backend. It shows 5 more matches by default when I click on it. You can see in below code that argument is set to 5. I want to get 20 more matches by clicking on the text.
Right Now I'm doing it manually by editing the HTML and replacing it with 20.
I want to do it using Selenium

```
<td colspan="6" class="last lastR">
   <a class="show_more"
      onclick="glib_show_hidden('','h2h_home',5); return false" 
      href="#">
         Show more matches <span class="arrow"></span>
   </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the attribute of this element:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(element_locator);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-ved', 'glib_show_hidden(\\'\\',\\'h2h_home\\',20); return false');",element);
```

for python:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-ved', 'glib_show_hidden(\\'\\',\\'h2h_home\\',20); return false');",element);
```

Comment: I'm using python,

Comment: So I replaced js.excecuteScript with driver.execute_script
but getting this error 
Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list